# libgdx powered iOS game not fullscreen on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, libgdx

I built a mobile game with libgdx 1.2.0 and Android works perfectly, but when I run the game on iOS simulator (iPhone 5, iOS 8) , it doesn't draw properly.

It's supposed to draw like this.
[image]

But there is a space on the right on iOS simulator.  It doesn't fit to the screen.
[image]

I'm very new to iOS, so could you tell me where to look at?

**EDIT:**
According to this issue https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2386 it seems I need the latest snapshot to fix this. I don't know how to work with the latest snapshot, so I'll wait for it by released. I'll update this question once I get the new version of libgdx.

Comment: did you try updating to latest version of libgdx? At the moment it is 1.3.1

Comment: @donfuxx I just updated to 1.3.1, but it didn't work.

Comment: What does your `resize` method look like? Are you using a Viewport subclass to handle sizing?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yup, I'm using StretchViewport from Scene2d. I'm at work now, so I can't post the code, but it's almost same as `create(){ stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(480, 320)); }` and `resize (int width, int height) {stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true); }` One thing I noticed is that if I don't set anything to UIInterfaceOrientation in info.plist, it's fitted in a portrait mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, newly release of 1.4.1 solved the problem. In case, someone doesn't know how to update libgdx.

1. Open build.gradle at an application root.
2. Change gdxVersion to '1.4.1'
3. Change roboVMVersion to '1.0.0-alpha-04'

I think you should also check https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/CHANGES for roboVM version libgdx uses.